# Как пройти бинарное дерево итератором?

Tags: java, бинарное-дерево, дерево

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как пройти бинарное дерево итератором? (`preorder`, `inorder`, `postorder`). Я создала алгоритмы для прохождения дерева в правильном порядке для `preorder` и  `postorder`, но очень плохо понимаю, как можно работать с итератором на примере дерева. (я имею право занимать в памяти только константную величину, то есть нельзя использовать `HashSet`, `ArrayList` и другие структуры с динамически меняющейся длиной).

Answer (score 1):

Сразу уточним, что в узлах дерева должны храниться ссылки на их родителей. В итераторе будем хранить только ссылку на текущий узел. Код будет на С++, но его несложно переписать на Java.

#### Preorder

Если у текущего узла есть левый потомок, то переходим в него. В противном случае, если есть правый потомок, то переходим в него. Если потомков нет, то надо подняться вверх по цепочке родителей, пока мы не встретим узел, у которого мы еще не посетили правого потомка, т.е. такой узел, в который мы придем слева в процессе подъема. Правый потомок этого узла будет следующим при обходе.

```
void PreorderIterator::Next() {
  if (current_->GetLeft()) {
    current_ = current_->GetLeft();
    return;
  }
  if (current_->GetRight()) {
    current_ = current_->GetRight();
    return;
  }
  while (true) {
    if (!current_->GetParent()) {
      current_ = NULL;
      break;
    }
    bool came_from_left_child = current_->GetParent()->GetLeft() == current_;
    current_ = current_->GetParent();
    if (came_from_left_child && current_->GetRight()) {
      current_ = current_->GetRight();
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Первым в обходе будет корень дерева.

#### Inorder

Если у текущего узла есть правое поддерево, то следующим узлом будет самый левый узел в этом поддереве. В противном случае надо подниматься вверх по цепочке родителей, пока мы не встретим родителя, в которого мы придем с левой стороны. Этот родитель и будет следующим узлом.

```
void InorderIterator::Next() {
  if (current_->GetRight()) {
    current_ = current_->GetRight();
    while (current_->GetLeft())
      current_ = current_->GetLeft();
    return;
  }
  while (true) {
    if (!current_->GetParent()) {
      current_ = NULL;
      break;
    }
    bool came_from_left_child = current_->GetParent()->GetLeft() == current_;
    current_ = current_->GetParent();
    if (came_from_left_child)
      break;
  }
}
```

Первым в обходе будет самый левый узел дерева.

#### Postorder

Самый простой случай. Переходим в родителя. Если мы пришли из левого потомка, и существует правый потомок, то переходим в самый левый узел правого поддерева. В противном случае остаемся в родителе.

```
void PostorderIterator::Next() {
  if (!current_->GetParent()) {
    current_ = NULL;
    return;
  }
  bool came_from_left_child = current_->GetParent()->GetLeft() == current_;
  current_ = current_->GetParent();
  if (came_from_left_child && current_->GetRight()) {
    current_ = current_->GetRight();
    while (current_->GetLeft())
      current_ = current_->GetLeft();
  }
}
```

Опять же, первым в обходе будет самый левый узел дерева.